# Rails 4, Capistrano 3 fail during bundle exec rake assets:precompile and returns rake stdout: Nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano, sshkit

Deploying with Capistrano fail during rake assets:precompile:

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.0.0-p353 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

The Prompt Respond with this error:

```
INFO [b438501f] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.0.0-p353 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile on 123.123.123.123

cap aborted!
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:142:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:166:in `block in _execute'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:59:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:89:in `with'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:58:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:57:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/osiris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
>
```

Here my **debloy.rb**

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'Myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:randomuser/myapp.git'

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/myapp'

set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.0.0-p353'

set :log_level, :info

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

set :keep_releases, 20

# SSHKit.config.output_verbosity = :debug
SSHKit.config.output = $stdout
SSHKit.config.output_verbosity = Logger::DEBUG
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "bundle exec rake"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, %{public/images public/javascripts public/stylesheets}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do

      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      within release_path do
        execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup"
end
```

You can find more details about this issue on this Gist:
https://gist.github.com/richardsondx/10092890
I noticed that the environment is not mentioned in the rake task even though I mentioned it in production.rb. It could help to overwrite the prefix the command with RAILS_ENV=production

I tried to overwrite the task with:

```
namespace :deploy do

  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile do
      on roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
        within release_path do
          with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
            execute :rake, "assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it didn't overwrite it.

Comment: try precompile assets in your local box, it's possible that you have errors in your sass or coffee/js files

Comment: Which gem are you using for the management of rvm with Capistrano ?
If you're using `capistrano-rvm`, I think, changing it to `rvm1-capistrano3` should help.

Comment: I had to up the ram on my VPS to 1G to compile assets.

Comment: Should worth a try? `with rails_env: :production do`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was dealing with the same problem in my VPN on DigitalOcean and I had to create the swap memory. My VPS was killing the assets precompile process.

Before creating swap memory, you can check if your server is using some swap memory using [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/). My server wasn't ...

Try this:

- Create 1GB swap memory

  `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/usr/mem.swap bs=1M count=512`
- Use the swap memory created in the first step

  `sudo mkswap /usr/mem.swap
  sudo swapon /usr/mem.swap`

Comment: This helps a lot, I saw this answer today, and could u explan the reason to this? And

Comment: Hi! some VPN hosts doesn't  have the swap memory enabled... unfortunately I don't know why. =/

Comment: for me swap was too small

Comment: Thank you Sagar Ranglani =D